# Arreglar problema de fecha PHP (CODEIGNITER)

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter

En un controlador estoy enviado 3 parametros a un model para que responda el booleano, y siempre me saca false, he hecho pruebas para que el model me retorne lo que esta recibiendo y esto es lo que me arroja..

```
["SE INGRESAN 10 NUEVOS PRODUCTOS AL STOCK ","01\/03\/2017","01\/05\/2017"]
```

Como podría hacer que reciba las fechas de una manera normal?

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function insert_productos()
    {
        $descripcion = 'SE INGRESAN 10 NUEVOS PRODUCTOS AL STOCK';//$this->input->post('descripcion');
        $fecha_inicial = "01/03/2017";//$this->input->post('fecha_inicial');
        $fecha_final = "01/05/2017";//$this->input->post('fecha_final');

        $response = $this->Periodo_model->insert_productos($descripcion,$fecha_inicial,$fecha_final);
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
```

**MODEL**

```
public function insert_productos($descripcion,$fecha_inicial,$fecha_final)
    {
        $stmt = $this->db->conn_id->prepare("INSERT INTO 
                                            public.per_periodo(
                                                per_id,
                                                per_descripcion,
                                                per_vigencia_inicial,
                                                per_vigencia_final)
                                            VALUES
                                                (DEFAULT,
                                                '$descripcion',
                                                '$fecha_inicial',
                                                '$fecha_final'");
        $result = $stmt->execute();
        return $result;
    }
```

**JS**

```
$('.datepicker').pickadate({
        selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
        selectYears: 15,// Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year
        /*format: 'yyyy/mm/dd',*/
        /*formatSubmit: 'yyyy-mm-dd',*/
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
        formatSubmit: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
        hiddenName: true,
        monthsFull: [ 'enero', 'febrero', 'marzo', 'abril', 'mayo', 'junio', 'julio', 'agosto', 'septiembre', 'octubre', 'noviembre', 'diciembre' ],
        monthsShort: [ 'ene', 'feb', 'mar', 'abr', 'may', 'jun', 'jul', 'ago', 'sep', 'oct', 'nov', 'dic' ],
        weekdaysFull: [ 'domingo', 'lunes', 'martes', 'miércoles', 'jueves', 'viernes', 'sábado' ],
        weekdaysShort: [ 'dom', 'lun', 'mar', 'mié', 'jue', 'vie', 'sáb' ],
        today: 'hoy',
        clear: 'borrar',
        close: 'cerrar',
        editable: true,
        min: 'today'
    });
```

Agradeceria su colaboración...

Comment: Y poniendo la fecha como "Año-mes-dia"?

Comment: de esa manera me funciona, pero no se guarda en la base de datos, ya que el dato que esta en la base de datos  es de tipo date y guarda la data o valores de esta manera 01/03/2017

Comment: Pareceria que el problema es que esta llegando a tu modelo la fecha con un slash de mas "01\/03\/2017" deberia ser "01/03/2017", has intentado quitar el slash sobrante antes de guardar?

Comment: Como dice @JuanPinzón de alguna manera estás escapando el caracter / con un \. No pongas el carácter \.
Si no lo estás poniendo tu, reemplaza el caracter \ por "" vacío.

Comment: @JuanPinzón creo que depronto te has confundido, ya que he dicho que el valor que me retorna es "01\/03\/2017" y el valor que tengo en mi variable es este "01/03/2017" si quito el slash quedaria un valor entero tipo string  por lo cual la base de datos tomaria eso como un string y no como una fecha

Comment: Pero en tu pregunta dices: he hecho pruebas para que el model me retorne lo que esta recibiendo y esto es lo que me arroja..

`["SE INGRESAN 10 NUEVOS PRODUCTOS AL STOCK ","01\/03\/2017","01\/05\/2017"]` se entiende que eso es lo que llega a tu modelo, o de donde obtienes esos datos?

Comment: si exacto, eso es lo que me retorna el modelo, pero para que el modelo me retorne tengo que enviar variables por medio de un  controlador, asi que se supondria que si en mi controlador tengo la variable $x = '01/05/2017' el modelo va a recibir ese dato por medio de una variable...espero haberme hecho entender

Comment: ¿Por qué utilizas PDO directamente en lugar de hacerlo a través de CodeIgniter con el método `query`?

Answer (score 1):

prueba con esto:

```
     $descripcion = $this->input->post('descripcion');

     $("#fecha_inicial" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "dd/mm/yy" ); 
     $("#fecha_final" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "dd/mm/yy" ); 

     $fecha_inicial = $this->input->post('fecha_inicial');
     $fecha_final = $this->input->post('fecha_final');
```

Comment: Pero esto usa JQuery, no? El autor no especifica que use Javascript.

Comment: @omar miranda ese es el codigo que tengo en mi JS y si lo imprimo en el controlador llega exactmanete igual pero cuando llega al modelo se estaya

Comment: verificaste si desde q llega a la funcion insert_productos ya llega mal

Comment: si, tanto en el controlador como en el js, si verifico en el controlador todo bien y si lo retorno en JS me lo retorna igual como se envia

Comment: me puedes pasar el codigo de como creas la fecha y la pasas por post para tener mas datos ya q el parece ser q aqui esta el problema y no en el controlador

Comment: @OmarMiranda ya monte el codigo que pides

Comment: no me pusiste el codigo de como la pasas al controlador

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54645/discussion-between-daniel-and-omar-miranda).

Answer (score 0):

Lo más probable es que esté fallando el comando `INSERT` al no poder interpretar las fechas correctamente, pero si no utilizas el método `query` no aprovechas las facilidades de CodeIgniter para depurar la consulta (método `error`).  Además es mejor utilizar el método `query` con la asignación de parámetros:

```
$result = $this->db->query(
    "INSERT INTO public.per_periodo(
        per_descripcion,
        per_vigencia_inicial,
        per_vigencia_final
    ) VALUES (?, ?, ?)",
    $this->db->escape($descripcion),
    $this->db->escape($fecha_inicial),
    $this->db->escape($fecha_final)
);

if (!$result) {
    $error = $this->db->error(); // Arreglo con información de error
}
```

Con este código estarías utilizando un comando parametrizado que mitiga el riesgo de inyección de código SQL, dejando que CodeIgniter se encargue de los detalles y en caso de error tienes acceso a un arreglo con la información del mismo.

Si cambias el formato de la fecha a `aaaa-mm-dd`, debería funcionar sin problemas si la columna en la base de datos es de tipo `DATE`.  En la base de datos las columnas de tipo `DATE` no se guardan con formato, pero sí importa el formato al momento de interpretar una cadena de caracteres como fecha.  Y `aaaa-mm-dd` es el formato *universal* que reconoce la mayoría de las conversiones de una cadena de caracteres a fecha.

Ahora bien, siempre debes verificar las entradas del usuario en todas las etapas:

- En el cliente/navegador
- En la aplicación (modelo)
- En la base de datos

Por lo tanto, el modelo debería verificar los datos antes de enviarlos a la base de datos.  Esto incluye verificar la validez de las fechas y que estén en el formato correcto.

Comment: Hola @Xint0 codeigniter es muy poderoso y facil de manejar, al usar PDO (que tambien es muy poderoso) no hay problema con usar una sentencia "basica, comun" o como se le pueda llamar, igualmente tienes mucha razon al utilizar las herramientas que codeigniter tiene para ofrecer....ya revise, voltie, mire y el problema era este --> ) <-- al final de la sentencia....igualmente muchas gracias por sacar un tiempo e interesarte porla duda que tenia..Saludos